# Определитель безопасности хранимой функции MySQL

Tags: mysql

Если не сложно, поясните пожалуйста принцип работы определителя безопасности хранимой процедуры MySQL.
Буду благодарен за ссылки на детальное самостоятельное изучение вопроса, но если не сложно то в двух словах: 
Чем будет отличаться поведение:
`DEFINER='%'@'localhost'` от `DEFINER='root'@'%'`
или
`INVOKER='%'@'localhost'` от `INVOKER='root'@'%'`
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Чем будет отличаться поведение:
>
> `DEFINER='%'@'localhost'` от `DEFINER='root'@'%'`
>
> или
>
> `INVOKER='%'@'localhost'` от `INVOKER='root'@'%'`

`'%'@'localhost'` - любой пользователь, но клиент запущен тут, на localhost. Любой пользователь с другой станции будет послан.

`'root'@'%'` - пользователь root с любой станции. Любой другой пользователь будет послан.

`DEFINER` - автор процедуры/функции.

`INVOKER` - тот, кто вызывает процедуру/функцию на выполнение.